# I don't want visual studio 2019 to auto-close apostrophe

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When i type ' visual studio automatically add another one, whether it makes sens or not in the situation.

I don't want double apostrophe every time I push it, in fact I never want that to happen, so much for " and maybe even (

Can I turn off this behavior somewhere ?

Comment: Tools > Options > Text Editor, somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > options > text Editor, as Hans suggested in the comments, then:

Click on a language you use (like C#, or HTML) and uncheck the checkbox that goes like "Automatically add closing bracket".

Repeat these 2 last operations for every other language you use.

Warning: This will cancel all the following automatics : {} '' () ""

There is no individual option for each of them (as far as I know).